# Hiding a <td> (from HTML) in Excel

Tags: php, html, excel, html-table

I am doing some reports that we display on a page, and then provide a link to the users to download the file. Most of the time for really simple reports we just push the HTML table into an xls file by setting the header while downloading.

The problem is, I can't seem to be able to hide a column in Excel, i.e. my column that is not visible on the webpage shows up in Excel. I tried saving an original xls document with a column hidden to HTML to see what shows up, it simply sets width=0 which I tried to replicate but it doesn't work for me.

Does anyone have any idea or a solution to simply hiding an entire HTML column when opened in Excel?

Comment: just realised that `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` doesn't work at all even when I use it with a `<span>` tag

Answer (score 2):

When an HTML file is opened by Excel, the parsing isn't particularly sophisticated, and it doesn't recognise every aspect of CSS. That's because HTML markup isn't a spreadsheet, and the ability to read that format into Excel is more a courtesy from Microsoft than a recognised spreadsheet format.

The sensible approach, if you want to use the more sophisticated features of Excel styling is to use one of the many PHP libraries that actually writes real Excel files rather than simply hoping you can massage HTML to render as you want it when opened in Excel. Personally, I'd recommend [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net), though I do have a vested interest as one of the developers.

Comment: I agree, PHPExcel is brilliant and we use it all the time. But this one report is supposed to be really simple and fast, without the overhead of using a library to output xls files.

Comment: As long as you're using HTML, you won't be able to create a column that is hidden when the file is opened in MS Excel... Excel's HTML parser just isn't that sophisticated. If you need that column to be hidden when opened in Excel, Excel will only recognise this when read from a real xls file

Answer (score 0):

You could also save the data you want displayed in some sort of array while your page is loading the table. Then you can just parse through the array and output "\n" for a new line and "\t" for a new cell to a .xls file handler. Not sure how sophisticated you want your tables to look but this is a simple solution for simple spreadsheets.